# Operations Research Journal format: figures' and tables' location

Tags: latex

in journal "Operation Research" author guidelines at https://pubsonline.informs.org/page/opre/submission-guidelines specify the order of things in a manuscript (`Preparing your manuscript`->`Format`),
and in there images and tables come last. Does this mean that one can not include tables and figures inside the main text? 
[image]

I've looked into the pertinent `LaTeX` styles, and there seem to be
no crucial difference between say "Management Science" (the only difference is an optional parameter in `documentclass`).

Comment: Maybe the `endfloat` package can help?

Answer (score 0):

With the `endfloat` package you can use your figures and tables inside the normal text and they will automatically be shown at the end of the document:

```
\documentclass[mnsc]{informs3}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```